# How to link to official PHP documentation in phpDocumentor 2?

Tags: php, phpdoc

I use the phpDocumentor 2 to describe few methods. I want to link to the official PHP documentation of a native function. I can write something like this:

```
/**
 * @see http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php ucfirst
 */
```

These don’t work:

```
/**
 * @see ucfirst
 * @see \ucfirst
 */
```

Is there a better way? I am looking for something like this:

```
/**
 * @the-official-documentation-for ucfirst
 */
```

Comment: i didn't get you? What you exactly trying to accomplish?

Comment: yes, you can write that.

Comment: @Anant I’ve updated question.

Comment: Ohk so you want to set documentation links above each code or function? Am i right? If yes i think the first one is correct

Comment: @Michas Yeah it should work. I have just tested and is not working on `Sublime text ` but works in `phpStorm`. You are true that official docs doesn't have the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You have some issue with your syntax in the documentation. You should use `@link` instead of `@see`.

```
/**
 * @see http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php ucfirst
 */
```

Change your documentation code to

```
/**
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php ucfirst
 */
```

I have tested it and is working on my editor i.e. `phpStorm`

**Note**: It only works in the `functions` and `class` names. You cannot use it on comments.

Comment: I don’t see any differences in the phpDocumentor 2 for `@see` and `@link`. In the draft of PSR-5 the `@link` is deprecated.